# Android Studio - Manually install dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I've dowloaded and installed Android Studio (in Ubuntu). During the setup, it started downloading many other dependencies. My internet is slow and Android Studio cannot download 2 large packages ( Android Support Repository & Android SDK Tools 25.2.2 ), downloads fail after a while.

I can manually download these packages from web browser, but how do I install them?

Links: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r39.zip & https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.2-linux.zip

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find your sdk location, such as "/opt/android-sdk-linux" in my computer. The repository should be moved into extras and Android SDK Tools 25.2.2 should be moved into buil-tools directory, hope it will work for you.